# Regex saying there are spaces in text when there is none

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, whitespace

I'm trying to check a string for spaces, tabs et al & am using this:

```
if (preg_match('/\s*/', $username)) {
    echo 'no spaces allowed in username.';
}
```

However it always thinks there are spaces in the username even if there isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you just have a *'Doh!' moment*

Comment: @ChrisMoutray Ahh yes I did lol...... been using `*` too much & forgot the `+` is what I needed in this instance lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` means zero or more times.

So

`if (preg_match('/\s+/', $username)) {`

Comment: Beat me to it. Although, really, to check for the presence of a space you don't need a quantifier at all.